# WP_Query freezing

Tags: wp-query

So I have stumbled across a number of similar questions on SO, but my understanding of wp_query and advanced PHP is limited. I think I am getting lost in the PHP objects / arrays and the use of `get_the_` and `the_` functions. The code is in (the roots theme equivalent of) funtions.php.

I am trying to debug as I go along by using `var_dump` and ChromePhp but often my page just crashes or freezes when I try and do this.

```
function tags() 
{
    // If current post has tags
    if (get_the_tags()) 
    {
        $post_id = get_the_id();
        $posttags = get_the_tags();

        // Loop for each tag the custom post has
        foreach($posttags as $tag) 
        {
            $tag_name = ($tag->slug);

            // Search for posts with the same tag,
            // is a custom type and don't return
            // the current post
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'custom_post',
                'tag' => $tag_name,
                'post__not_in' => array( $post_id )
                );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Make sure we got results
            if( $query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                // Loop through each returned post
                while ( $query->have_posts() )
                {
                    $query->the_post(); // Returns null

                    ...other things generally lock up the page...


                    $example = ($query->posts[0]); // Crashes the server

                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('shortcodetag', 'tags');
```

So this seems to work OK to a point, I can return the correct posts based on the current tag. The problem is simply accessing the information in these returned posts. The final while loop just grinds the page to a halt for 30s before I get a server error.

Comment: do you call `$query->the_post()` inside your loop?

Comment: @Milo - I get `null`

Comment: it doesn't return anything, it advances the internal counter and populates the current post, otherwise `$query->have_posts()` will return true forever and the loop will never terminate.

Comment: Where is `$posttags` generated

Comment: When does the 'tags' function get called? What happens inside the loop? What exactly are you doing when this WP_Query occurs?

Comment: `$tag_name = ($tag->name);` should be `$tag_name = $tag->slug;`

Comment: @TomJNowell - I want to access data in the returned posts within my loop - a trivial example could be title, but rather than wp functions, I am trying to access this information in the returned objects and arrays with PHP

Comment: Also remember to reset your query with `wp_reset_postdata();`

Comment: Please reread my previous two comments

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have updated the question. I am curious though why slug is preferred over name - as name is within the returned object

Comment: @myol If you check the codex, the `tag` parameter in `WP_Query` accepts the tag slug, not the name

Comment: @Milo ok I sort of understand, but why is it needed at all? Shouldn't the loop terminate when `$query->have_posts()` becomes false?

Comment: @myol I'm sorry but I still don't understand why you're doing what you're doing? Can we see the code in ***full***? It's clear the code that calls `tags` and the code inside the loop is both important and missing from your question. As a side note only use `wp_reset_query` when using `query_posts`

Comment: calling `$query->the_post()` is what makes `$query->have_posts()` eventually return false. `$query->the_post()` increments a var, `$query->have_posts()` checks the value of that var. it also populates the current post vars, otherwise template tags would fetch the data from the first post in the loop for every iteration.

Comment: you cannot use `tag` as your shortcode name, it is a [reserved name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms). Also, where are you calling this shortcode

Comment: Just one thing here, are you actually using build-in tags with a custom post type?

Comment: @PieterGoosen - Yes I was trying to use the built in tags with my custom post type

Comment: @TomJNowell - I've added the code which calls the function (its shortcode) - But the code within the loop, I cannot, nothing seems to work for me. I basically want to manipulate the stuff inside the returned post - but I don't know what variable to call or anything

Comment: And on my question, where and how are you using your shortcode. This is very important. Another question, are you trying to use this as related posts

Comment: @PieterGoosen - Literally the shortcode is on a single-custom_template_page.php used by `<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcodetag]'); ?>` | As for your other question, yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, but I want to pick and choose what is displayed, which is why I'm trying to access the objects/elements within the returned posts object

Comment: OK, I'm going to post an answer on what was given.

Comment: If you're calling do_shortcode, why would you bother with a shortcode at all, just call the function directly

Comment: I totally agree with @TomJNowell A shortcode is overkill here. Just make use of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in comments to your question, here is what I suggest and recommend

Just to recap and to add everything in a constructive answer

- The [`tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) parameter in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) accepts the term **slug**, not the **name**
- Always reset your custom `WP_Query`, always. Make use of `wp_reset_postdata()` after your query is done, just before `endif`
- You cannot use `tag` as your shortcode name, it is a [reserved name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) in Wordpress

I believe that your order of doing things is what is causing all of your headaches. Also, a shortcode should `return` its output, not `echo` it. Have a look at the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) on how to create a shortcode

Before you check anything in your code or if a post have tags, you actually have to get the current post. Without this, your code won't work. So, the first thing to do is to call your global `$post`. Once you have that, you can pass the ID to [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)

Your code should be working once this is done

Here is an example: (*Caveat: untested*)

```
add_shortcode('shortcodetag', 'tags');
function tags() {
    ob_start();
    global $post;

    $posttags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
   if ( $posttags ) 
    {
        // Loop for each tag the custom post has
        foreach($posttags as $tag) 
        {
            $tag_name = ($tag->slug);

            // Search for posts with the same tag,
            // is a custom type and don't return
            // the current post
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'custom_post',
                'tag' => $tag_name,
                'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
                );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Make sure we got results
            if( $query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                // Loop through each returned post
                while ( $query->have_posts() )
                {
                    $query->the_post(); // Returns null

                    //LOOP ELEMENTS

                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        }
    }

     $myvariable = ob_get_clean();

     return $myvariable;

}
```

**EDIT**

As @TomJNowell suggested, I don't really see the use of a shortcode here. You'll be doing a `do_shortcode` in your single template. This is exactly the same as just calling the function directly.

Here is an example to demonstrate this, and if I understand your comment correctly, an example how to display certain post elements using template tags

```
function tags() {
global $post;

$posttags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
   if ( $posttags ) 
    {
        // Loop for each tag the custom post has
        foreach($posttags as $tag) 
        {
            $tag_name = $tag->slug;

            // Search for posts with the same tag,
            // is a custom type and don't return
            // the current post
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'custom_post',
                'tag' => $tag_name,
                'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
                );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Make sure we got results
            if( $query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                // Loop through each returned post
                while ( $query->have_posts() )
                {
                    $query->the_post(); // Returns null
                        //LOOP ELEMENTS
                    the_title(); //display post title
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                        the_post_thumbnail(); //display the featured image
                    } 
                    the_content(); //displays the post's content

                }
wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the best way to loop through the elements?

Comment: See my update as well.